# CoreData and NSInvalidArgumentException unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios5, nsmanagedobject

I keep running into this exception when trying to set my property "phoneNumber":

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-   [SearchResult setPhoneNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x256b40'

Here's the class with the phoneNumber property:

```
@interface SearchResult : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * phoneNumber;
@end

@implementation SearchResult
@dynamic phoneNumber;
@end
```

Issue is that when I do this:

```
SearchResult *managedObject = [self findExistingSearchResultById:restaurantId];

if(managedObject == nil)
{ 
    managedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SearchResult" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
}

// Exception throws here.
managedObject.phoneNumber = @"1234567890";
```

Here's the findExistingSearchResult method:

```
+ (SearchResult *)findExistingSearchResultById:(NSString *)restaurantId
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = serviceContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SearchResult" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"restaurantId = %@", restaurantId];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if(fetchedObjects != nil)
    {
        return [fetchedObjects lastObject];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

I'm using very similar class implementations across my app, and not running into any issues like this. I haven't figured out why setting phoneNumber property here throws this exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. Though I switched computers, and the issue disappeared. I checked in my latest code, and got latest on my other machine, and Xcode is no longer throwing this exception. I'm not  quite understanding the cause of the issue though, because I had tried several clean builds to no avail...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to instantiate a `NSManagedObject` using a conventional alloc/init method of `NSObject`.

If you want to use CoreData you have to use the NSManagedObject designated initialiser, as described on the class reference documentation for `NSManagedObject`

> NSManagedObject is a generic class that implements all the basic
>   behavior required of a Core Data model object. It is not possible to
>   use instances of direct subclasses of NSObject (or any other class not
>   inheriting from NSManagedObject) with a managed object context. You
>   may create custom subclasses of NSManagedObject, although this is not
>   always required. If no custom logic is needed, a complete object graph
>   can be formed with NSManagedObject instances.
>
> A managed object is associated with an entity description (an instance
>   of NSEntityDescription) that provides metadata about the object
>   (including the name of the entity that the object represents and the
>   names of its attributes and relationships) and with a managed object
>   context that tracks changes to the object graph. It is important that
>   a managed object is properly configured for use with Core Data. If you
>   instantiate a managed object directly, you must call the designated
>   initializer (initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:).

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html

Comment: Apologies, I didn't include all of the code which created the problem, and you're answer I believe is certainly correct given my original code. I've just updated to show further of what I'm doing. I just checked in all of my code, and opened my project with latest check-in on another computer of mine in Xcode, and issue seems to have gone away though. I had tried a clean build several times, I wonder if Xcode has some sort of issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and couldn't resolve.  Ultimately I deleted the property from the xcdatamodel file, then re-added it, cleaned, and rebuilt.  Finally worked after many other things had failed.